# How to call a previous function in a new function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

How can I refer to a previous function in a new function in python 2.7.
For instance, say if I want to display the result which function1 calculated in function2. How would I go about this?

Comment: Return the results from function1. Set the return value to a variable in function2 and print it out.

Comment: If you can't find the answer to this via google or whatever tutorial/book etc you are using to learn Python, then you're in deep trouble.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is right. You might want to paste your code so we could explain in a better way

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a lack of research. Every online python tutorial shows how to call one function from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wouldn't it be:

```
def func_one():
    return 2 + 2

def func_two():
    x = func_one()
    print x

func_two()
#output: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the flow of your program.  A function doesn't run until it is called.  When it is called, it may return a value (if you say it calculates something, it should return that).  That return value is available to the caller of the function, but not to any other functions.  So function2 cannot use it.  Unless it is passed that value as an argument, that is:

```
def function1():
    return 42

def function2(value):
    print('The value is %d' % value)

x = function1()
function2(x)
```